# Does a Postgres VACUUM free up space for any database object?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

If I do a `VACUUM` on a Postgres table (without the `FULL` option) I know that it should make any free-space available to the database, but *not* the operating system.

Should it make the freespace available to any database object? or just the table that's been vacuumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a `VACUUM` the table will be as big as before, just more of the space will be free and available for future `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s. In other words, the file won't shrink <sup>(1)</sup>. So the space will not be available for other tables, only for the table that has been vacuumed.

Note (1): Sometimes the file *will* shrink. If the last block is completely empty after the `VACUUM`, PostgreSQL will try to truncate all empty blocks off the end of the table.

Comment: So, If I want to do a space-consuming operation on TABLE_A, there's no point in doing a simple VACUUM on TABLE_B, TABLE_C, TABLE_D or TABLE_E because it won't free up any space for TABLE_A ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can use the `pg_total_relation_size()` function to measure the size of a table and all that goes with it.

Comment: Thanks, wish I'd known that years ago! That's a big revelation to me, for to long I've assumed that if I needed DB space for a big operation then a simple VACUUM on all the other tables would do the trick. Obviously not!